# How to insert pandas.series object in 1 cell in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
     |  col1  |  col2  |  col3  |
-----|--------|--------|--------|
  0  |  apple |  apple |  apple |
```

And I have a `pandas.Series` object that looks like this `["banana", "potato", "tomato"]`

I want to create a new column, `col4`, into the dataframe and either fill it with an empty list, `[]`, or the `pandas.Series` object. I want it to be on 1 row (index 0 in this case) but everytime I do this I get the following error:

`Length of values does not match length of index`

So I think it's trying something like:

```
     |  col1  |  col2  |  col3  |  col4  |
-----|--------|--------|--------|--------|
  0  |  apple |  apple |  apple | banana |
  1  |        |        |        | tomato |
  2  |        |        |        | potato |
```

which is not what I want.

What I want is:

```
     |  col1  |  col2  |  col3  |              col4              |
-----|--------|--------|--------|--------------------------------|
  0  |  apple |  apple |  apple | ["banana", "tomato", "potato"] |
```

As a sidenote I already did it by converting the list to string but then the column is of type `string`, and since I want to upload to Google Big Query as a `RECORD` it doesn't work for me.

I tried many things and none worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
In [649]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['apple'], 'col2':['apple'], 'col3':['apple']})                                                                                                                         

In [650]: s = pd.Series(["banana", "potato", "tomato"])                                                                                                                                                     

In [661]: df['col4'] = [s.tolist()]                                                                                                                                                                         

In [662]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[662]: 
    col1   col2   col3                      col4
0  apple  apple  apple  [banana, potato, tomato]
```